# Using a SASS list item as a variable name

Tags: sass

I am currently trying to loop through a SASS list and use the items within it to match up with variable names I have in my code so that I can then use those variables inside the loop while also using the list string to create a class.

What I've got at the moment is this ...

```
$sections: upcoming messages profile area report;

@each $section in $sections {
    .#{$section} {
        h2 { color: $#{$section};   }
        h2:after { background-color: $#{$section}; }
    }
}
```

My assumption is that I can't use "$section" inside the "#{}" but if that is the case what is the correct way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following solution works for Sass 3.3

```
//make sure the color variables are defined before calling the @each function
$upcoming: green;
$messages: yellow;
$profile: red;
$area: blue;
$report: black;


$sections: (upcoming: $upcoming, messages: $messages, profile: $profile, area: $area, report: $report);

@each $section, $color in $sections {
   .#{$section} {
      h2 { color: $color }
      h2:after { background-color: $color }
    }
}
```

and you'll get the following css:

```
.upcoming h2 {
   color: green;
}

.upcoming h2:after {
   background-color: green;
}

.messages h2 {
   color: yellow;
}

.messages h2:after {
  background-color: yellow;
}
...
```